# Predictable random sequences depending on related seeds

Tags: algorithm, random, numbers, prng

I've had this idea in my head for quite a while, but I failed to articulate it in a searchable way, so I thought I'd ask it as a question. There is a lot of information about seeds and RNG algorithms, but I couldn't find much information about the relationship between the two. Many of the discussions derail into mathematical equations that seem to talk about the distribution of the series, rather then the difference between two given series and two seeds.

More to the point, I'm interested in a behaviour like this: [Two different seeds producing the same 'random' sequence](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13364401/two-different-seeds-producing-the-same-random-sequence).
In short, two different seeds (that are somewhat close to each other in the byte representation) generate very similar random number sequences. I would like to have a similar behaviour, preferably with a simple-enough condition along the lines of "the farther the two seeds are from each other the more different the two series will be".

Some additional background (in case there's a better approach that I'm completly overlooking): 
I'm playing around with some genetic algorithms where this sort of behaviour would be very desirble to me. I generate a few random numbers and use them to explore a very wide space of options. Later, I test those numbers out and evaluate the "goodness" of that sequence. Once I find a sequence that has a decent score, I would like to be able to generate a similar repeatable random sequence in my next generation, except I'd like it to be a little different from the first sequence, but only slightly (Thus more likely to perserve the "goodness" of the result).

I am using the seeds as the "identifier" of the sequence, so that if the first 20 numbers in the sequence are good for me, I could produce additional "good numbers" later on. Is there any algorithms where a simple relationship between the seeds will represent some sort of relationship between the series?

My apologies for the very vague question, the whole thing confuses me quite a bit...

[Disclaimer: I have an "ok" understanding of what these algorithms do , I just can't really map from a relationship between seeds to relationship on the series]

Answer (score 1):

I am doubtful, that such a thing as a generalizable reliable measure for the similarity of (pseudo-)random sequences exists: Consider this example (assuming we produce random bytes, i.e. 0-255)

Sequence A: 5-6-7-8-9-10

- Sequence B1: 105-106-107-108-109-110
- Sequence B2: 95-94-93-92-91-90
- Sequence B3: 6-5-8-7-10-9
- Sequence B4: 10-9-8-7-6-5

Which of B1-B4 would be the most similar to A?

Comment: I understand that a generalizable measure for similarity is probably not something that I could achieve. I would be interested what sort of similarities I can achieve though. :)
Part of the problem is that I can't really think of a good way to express the similarity.
The two (again, not very concreat) similarities I had in mind would produce none of the B sequences you offered. I look at the sequence as an "ordered set", so A and B3 are completely different for me.
I would prefer:
B5: 4-5-6-7-8-9 / 6-7-8-9-10-11 ("shifted" sequence) or 
B6: 5-6-55-8-9-137 ("Noise" in the original sequence)

Comment: Your B5 is exatly my B1 - with a shift of 2 instead of a shift of 100.

Comment: It would be, if the last element was 110. But yes, if that was the intent, that is one of the possibilities I would like to explore. Do you know of any way to cause the "seed" of the series to generate that sort of a shift?

Comment: If you are in for shifted sequences, I propose using one constant random sequence for the intervals and another varying random number for the offset. Maybe with a third, very dampened sequence making the noise

Comment: That's a very interesting idea! I will experiment with this, thanks!